# Add a keyword to C# with code generation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-generation, metalanguage

I have a domain specific language that I would like to interact with C# by adding new keywords (or some keyword-like syntax). Using attributes would be insufficient (I can't use them in method bodies), and shoehorning it into 'valid' C# notation that gets compiled into something else would be ugly and ruin the analogy with the DSL (and the translation from DSL-like notation to C# is nontrivial, so just writing the C# each time is out of the question).

I already have a way to parse the .cs file and transform it into legitimate, nontrivial, C# code which can be compiled.

The problem is, even through I can do all the work of defining the DSL, parsing it, and translating it into valid C#, Visual Studio won't let me use notation it doesn't understand; it just adds red squiggles, emits an error "cannot resolve symbol", and then often fails to properly parse things after it.

Is there a way to to force visual studio to ignore specific strings in its analysis? I've looked at visual studio plugins but it looks like, although I can do syntax highlighting and other stuff, I can't force it to ignore something it doesn't know how to parse (unless I'm missing some way to do that in the extension API, which is certainly possible).

I've skimmed through the Roslyn stuff and don't see offhand a way to do this there, either. (Again, may be missing something, it doesn't seem to have great documentation.)

Comment: You can't force VS to understand your C# syntax because it is, well, not a valid C# syntax. It is your DSL, not a C#. You can change the extension of your file to convince VS that it's not a C# file, and define a syntax highlighter plug-in for that new language.

Comment: I don't want it to understand the syntax--I have a prebuild process that understands it. I want it to *ignore* the syntax.

Comment: Changing the extension should do the trick then: VS will ignore the syntax of your file, treating it as text.

Comment: I don't want it treated as text, I want it treated as valid C# because aside from a few references to the DSL it is valid C#...

Comment: That's my point: you cannot have VS treat your code as valid C# unless it is pure, 100% valid, C#. The "almost valid" is a synonym for "invalid" - plain and simple. Of course, there are ways to make it valid - for example, by disguising your DSL as comments in some special format that your parser understands. In this case, your language would be a valid C# again, and the VS is not going to complain.

Comment: This can be done in, e.g., C++ with Visual Studio. What's the obstruction to doing it with C#?

Comment: The difference is that C++ is a different language, it's not a C# with a new keyword or two. VS has a separate processor for it to do parsing and highlighting - precisely what I suggested to do for your DSL in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PowerLanguages.E: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a512e0d0-f4f3-4435-bad4-8d5efbb1db4a

No english docs yet, sorry